# Why this simple code for increment numbers doesn't work?

Tags: php, session

I want to make just simple incrementing with session but the session just stop every time on 2. Can you please help me what I should do?

```
 if (!isset($_SESSION["current"]))
 {
 $_SESSION["current"] = 1;
 } 
 $_SESSION["current"] = $_SESSION["current"] +1;
 echo "SESSION: ".$_SESSION["current"]."<br>CURRENT: ";
```

I tryed this code and it doesnt work too:

```
<?php    
if (isset($_POST["previous"]))
{
 $_SESSION["current"] = $_SESSION["current"] - 1;
}           

if (isset($_POST["next"]))
{
$_SESSION["current"] = $_SESSION["current"] + 1;
}

echo "SESSION: ".$_SESSION["current"]."<br>CURRENT: "; 
?>
```

Comment: "What stops"? The value in '$_SESSION' or the value in '$current'? Providing the output would likely clear this up.

Comment: Do you ever call `session_start()`?

Comment: I edited my post and session_start calls my webhosting

Comment: "session_start calls my webhosting" -> what do you mean? Also, `$current` isn't defined.

Comment: It stops on 2 if the $current is not defined

Comment: I mean when I was typing on support of my webhosting they said that I dont have to write there session_start() (btw it throws me error when i typed there) and variable $current is not in use i will edit my post

Comment: Your $_SESSION["current"] is for what purpose? remember that session variables are bind to browser that you use.

Comment: @McBern It is for slide manager in php

Comment: Anything from error reporting? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - in all pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to use this "current" value for pagination. If that is the case you are going about it a bit wrong. Remember the session will store the last value set until it is destroy or reset with another value. Here is my take

```
<?php   
    session_start(); // according to you, you don't need this so please remove

    $current = 0; // lowest value for our pagination

    if(isset($_SESSION['current'])){
        $current = $_SESSION['current']; // session has an entry
    }


    if ((isset($_POST["previous"]) || isset($_POST['next'])))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['previous'])){
            $current -=  1; // for previous
        }else{
            $current += 1; // for next
        }

        $current  = ($current >= 0)?$current: 0; // reset to 0 when we get to negative
    }else{
        $current = 0; // we maybe back on the "start page"               
    }           


   $_SESSION['current'] = $current;

   echo "SESSION: ".$_SESSION["current"]."<br>CURRENT: ";
```

Answer (score 0):

That code should work, maybe your session is not active. try to issue this on top of your script:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}`
```